# MOD_WSGI : "SERVER_NAME"( of php) equivalency in Python or WSGI?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, httpd.conf

Suppose there are 100 domain names pointed to my
server's IP address.

and I have not set up VirtualHosts for these domains.
and I do not plan on..

But what I want to do is simply extract what is before the`.com`so if the domain nameis:`111.com`all i want is the **"111"** value.my index page is a wsgi script. which means.. 
when these domains come to my server IP ..i can simply extract the value before the .com
depending on the value.. i can return different content..
and thus eliminate the need for creating VirtualHosts and so on via Apache and httpd.conf
is this a viable method.
if so.. i also would like to know the PHP equivalence for..`SERVER_NAME`
so that i can extract domains that point to my server ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`environ` argument](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables) passed to the WSGI application handler contains the items normally found in `$_SERVER` in PHP, including a "SERVER_NAME" item.

```
print >>sys.stderr, environ['SERVER_NAME']
```